# how to do 301 redirect of the same URL with a difference in hypen

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, nginx, webserver

I have two links that are actually the same content, for some reason google traced it as two URL, one is:

```
http://www.shopious.com/items/818526/Celine-Trapeze-mini-Suede-1-warna-saja-185rb-
```

and the other one is:

```
http://www.shopious.com/items/818526/Celine-Trapeze-mini-Suede-1-warna-saja-185rb
```

I basically wanted to redirect the one that has the - at the end to the one that doesn't have the - . How can I do this in nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule :

```
rewrite ^/(items/[0-9]+/.+?)-$ /$1 permanent;
```

Comment: but this will then redirect http://www.shopious.com/shops/jelly- to http://www.shopious.com/shops/jelly right? which is not what I want, the format needs to he www.shopious.com/items/somenumberhere/somestringhere @anubhava

Comment: @anuvbhava and that is also for Apache, I am using nginx

Comment: I just added that into my config and restarted nginx.. however it doesn't redirect @anubhava

Comment: Sorry I don't have nginx to test at present. Can you try: `rewrite ^/(items/[0-9]+/.+?)-$ /$1 permanent;` rule and restart.

Comment: okay now that one works.. revise your answer and I will accept it